# Why is my array not updating its values when asked?

Tags: python, numpy, initialization

I'm working with 2D numpy arrays as matrices. I am attempting to fill in values after initializing it with `np.zeros`. While some of these values fill in without an issue, others do not. I can print the values immediately beforehand, but after attempting to set the element to that value, it remains 0.

Here's the matrix I'm working with, and the relavent section of code

```
#Initialize A

A_row1 = np.array([2,-1,4,0])
A_row2 = np.array([4,-1,5,1])
A_row3 = np.array([-2,2,-2,3])
A_row4 = np.array([0,3,-9,4])

A = np.array([A_row1,A_row2,A_row3,A_row4])

def Elem(A,row):
    pivot = A[row,row]

    #Initialize E as identity
    E = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),int)
    for i in range(len(A)):
        E[i,i] = 1

    for i in np.arange(row+1,len(A)):
        row_val = A[i,row]
        print(-row_val/pivot)
        E[i,row] = -row_val/pivot
        print(E[i,row])

print(Elem(A,0))
```

Here's the part I really don't understand. When running as is, the output is as expected. It takes A[1:4,0], divides them by A[0,0], and places them in the correct location.

```
-2.0
-2
1.0
1
0.0
0
[[ 1  0  0  0]
 [-2  1  0  0]
 [ 1  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1]]
```

However, if I swap the first two rows, the line `E[i,row] = -row_val/pivot` doesn't do its job and the output is

```
-0.5
0
0.5
0
0.0
0
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]
```

I have been scratching my head at this for the last couple of hours. Can someone make this make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When initializing `E`, you specify it as an array of `int`s.

```
    E = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),int)
```

So when you try to assign `-0.5` or `0.5` to an element of `E`, they get converted to `int`s.

Just replace with the following line if you want to allow `float`s in E too.

```
    E = np.zeros((len(A),len(A)),float)
```

Comment: You could also want to check what happens when you leave that parameter empty.

Comment: Of course, can't believe I didn't notice that. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest I only noticed it because I spent half a day debugging something similar recently.